# Exact procedure to add an image through json android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, imageview

Hello so I have already an expirience with AsyncTask so I can manage to get some data with PHP scripts from an SQL Server and parsed them with JSON. Now what I would want is to know how can I use the AsyncTask in order to load images to some activities. Also is there anyway that I can call the AsyncTask before the app starts? because that would be really helpful too.

I don't have any adapters I am just using this for the AsyncTask:

```
    // The definition of our task class
       private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
           private String postName;
           private JSONObject jsonvar = new JSONObject();
       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
       }

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
             this.postName = params[0];




             String status = "";
             List<NameValuePair> values = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             values.add( new BasicNameValuePair( "username", this.postName ) );



            final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance( "" );
            HttpResponse response = HttpHelper.postResponse( client, Register.phpUrl, values );
            String data = HttpHelper.getData( response );
            try {
                jsonvar = new JSONObject(data);
                status=jsonvar.getString("status");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            client.close();

            return status;     
            }

//     @Override
//     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
//        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
//     }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String status) {
           String session = "", status_message = " ";
            try {
                status_message = jsonvar.getString("status_message");
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
          super.onPostExecute(status);

                }

            }
       }
```

Comment: I want to hear why did you give minus 1. Can you explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

As i can tell with information provided, supposing that what you read from your server is the image URL and obtain it in JSON format, what i would do is writing a listener to your AsyncTask, calling it in `onPostExecute` method, and loading it in your Activity using [PicassoImagesLoader](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Something like:

```
private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    public interface onLoadFinishedListener {
        public void onLoadFinished(JSONObject response)
    }

    protected JSONObject onPostExecute(JSONObject response){
        onLoadFinished(response);
    }
}
```

And in your Activity:

```
public myActivity extends Activity implements PostTask.onLoadFinishedListener {


    @Override
    onLoadFinished(JSONObject response){
        Picasso.with(this).load(response.getString("url")).into(imageView);
    }
}
```

Something like this would help :)

Comment: What if I want to load more than one? I mean  an array of strings (urls) which they will turn to images with Picasso. Lets say that the json encode returns me back 5 rows which they contain 5 differents urls. Is it possible? and if yes how

Comment: Just make as much calls as necessary to Picasso.with().load(url1)... Picasso.with().load(url2)...

Comment: So I can do this without JSON, as you say it if I know the exact url. That's why I need you to tell me how to get the url as an array and be able to work with them in order to take the image. If it's possible please update and your code :)

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you're saying. What you pass a parameter to Picasso.load() method is the URL of the image you want to load, if you want to load more than one you're going to need the URL of each image, which you can read from your server via JSON (with a JSONArray or something similar). If i'm still misunderstanding you please let me know and i'll try to do my best :)

Comment: Yes I understand that, but when you are saying load more, how exactly am I going to do that? with JSONArray? and how? and I am sorry if I am not understandable.

Comment: Ok i'll try to explain better ^^ I'm going to suppose that what you've got on your server is a lot of URLs pointing to the images you want to load on your Android application. With the AsyncTask you wrote (or modifying it), you should be able to read those URLs from the server regardless of the format (that's your choice), the point is that in the AsyncTask.onPostExecute(response) you are going to have an array with the URLs of the images, am i wrong? With this array you should be able to load such images with Picasso.load(array[0]), Picasso.load(array[1])... and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57855/discussion-between-pap-and-sherekan).